# How to resolve Git error: "fatal: BUG: get_tempfile_fd() called for inactive object"

Tags: git

When doing a `git pull` on a repo I work in everyday, I received the following error:

```
fatal: BUG: get_tempfile_fd() called for inactive object
```

That's all the error said.  What does it mean and what do I do?

Comment: That's an internal Git error. You can report it to the Git maintainers, and/or switch to a different version of Git (run `git --version` to see which version you have). Meanwhile it may be worth trying to split the `git pull` into its two separate steps, `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` (default) or `git rebase` (usually the right thing to do but *not* the default); maybe the two-step method won't tickle the bug in your version of Git.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The resolution for me was was deleting `.git/index.lock`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem for me was that I didn't have permissions for the directory I was in, so switching to the correct user fixed it for me. Simple fix but you can easily overlook it.

Answer (score 3):

This is often a permissions error. On Linux you can `chown` the folder or switch to the appropriate user.

Use `ls -la` within the parent folder to see the user permissions. If this is indeed the problem, you can `chown` the folder recursively.

If my folder name containing the repository was `happytimes` and my name was `daniel` I would do:

`sudo chown -R daniel:daniel happytimes`

Comment: This. Ran into the same after I did `sudo cp -r "source" "target"` for a GitHub project.